# Retrieve Unicode code points > U+FFFF from QChar

Tags: qt, unicode, astral-plane, codepoint, qchar

I have an application that is supposed to deal with all kinds of characters and at some point display information about them. I use Qt and its inherent Unicode support in QChar, QString etc.

Now I need the code point of a QChar in order to look up some data in http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt, but QChar's unicode() method only returns a ushort (unsigned short), which usually is a number from 0 to 65535 (or 0xFFFF). There are characters with code points > 0xFFFF, so how do I get these? Is there some trick I am missing or is this currently not supported by Qt/QChar?

Comment: Btw, QString docs start with "The QString class provides a Unicode character string.

QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars, where each QChar corresponds one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive QChars.)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `QChar` is a UTF-16 value, not a complete Unicode codepoint. Therefore, non-BMP characters consist of two `QChar` surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 3):

The solution appears to lay in code that is documented but not seen much on the Web. You can get the utf-8 value in decimal form. You then apply to determine if a single QChar is large enough. In this case it is not. Then you need to create two QChar's.

```
uint32_t cp = 155222; // a 4-byte Japanese character 
QString str;
if(Qchar::requiresSurrogate(cp))
{
    QChar charArray[2];
    charArray[0] = QChar::highSurrogate(cp);
    charArray[1] = QChar::lowSurrogate(cp);
    str =  QString(charArray, 2);
}
```

The resulting QString will contain the correct information to display your supplemental utf-8 character.

Answer (score 2):

### Unicode characters beyond U+FFFF in Qt

`QChar` itself only supports Unicode characters up to `U+FFFF`.

`QString` supports Unicode characters beyond `U+FFFF` by **concatenating two QChars** (that is, by using UTF-16 encoding). However, the QString API doesn't help you much if you need to process characters beyond `U+FFFF`. As an example, a QString instance which contains the single Unicode character `U+131F6` will return a size of 2, not 1.

I've opened [QTBUG-18868](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-18868) about this problem back in 2011, but after more than three years (!) of discussion, it was finally closed as "out of scope" without any resolution.

### Solution

You can, however, download and use [these Unicode Qt string wrapper classes](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/31415/QUtfString.zip) which have been attached to the Qt bug report. Licensed under the LGPL.

This download contains the wrapper classes `QUtfString`, `QUtfChar`, `QUtfRegExp` and `QUtfStringList` which supplement the existing Qt classes and allow you to do things like this:

```
QUtfString str;
str.append(0x1307C);            // Some Unicode character beyond U+FFFF

Q_ASSERT(str.size() == 1);
Q_ASSERT(str[0] == 0x1307C);

str += 'a';

Q_ASSERT(str.size() == 2);
Q_ASSERT(str[1] == 'a');
Q_ASSERT(str.indexOf('a') == 1);
```

For further details about the implementation, usage and runtime complexity please see the API documentation included within the download.